# Galaxy S4 Android 4.3 is repeatingly asking about TouchWiz

Tags: samsung-touchwiz

Every time I press the home button Android asks me to choose between Standard and Simple. How can I can rid of this annoyance?

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

### update 131130 16:26 CET

I installed another launcher and tried to clear and disable everything with TouchWiz and still it's repeadingly asking me the same question every time I press the home button.

[image]
[image]

### Update 131201 10:47 CET

I [read](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/326154-home-key-complete-action-using-touchwiz-easy-home-huh.html) that rebooting the phone and/or uninstalling the google search update could resolve the problem and after rebooting the phone the question hasn't popped up for a while. I'm clicking around to verify that it won't appear and the solution at this time seems to be that rebooting the phone will do it and I might not have to uninstall the search update which was mentioned.

Comment: Wouldn't this be Android 4.3?

Comment: I'm assuming you selected Touchwiz and then 'Always' (I'm guessing Alltid means always) and that didn't work. Maybe go to settings > more > application manager and clear the touchwiz defaults and try it again. Could you install Nova Launcher (it's free) and try to set your default home in Nova Settings (you can select TW in there).

Comment: @RossC Rebooting the phone seems to have solved it.

Comment: I found the solution on another blog, seems to be working. http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/334381-touchwiz-wont-stay-default-launcher.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for uninstalling the Touchwiz from S4.

1. Press and hold on the home button. (the centre button on your Samsung mobile)
2. You will see a screen with a bar below, on the bar. There is 3 icons. Press on the pie icon.
3. Select clear default, and press the home button again. (Just press and release, do not hold)
4. Once you see the Touchwiz appear with 2 selections. Touchwiz Home Easy and Touchwiz Home. Select only Touchwiz Home and press always.
5. The Touchwiz will not bother you again.

Answer (score -1):

You need not reboot or anything. The only thing you have to do is go to settings and select from default applications touch wiz home once and forever.